# In my eclipse rcp application, table.getSelection() is returning the selected rows from a different tab

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am currently developing an eclipse rcp application using Kepler.

My application can have multiple tabs which each contains a table of different data. There is a button on the tab to add a row to the table within the tab. However when I open more than one tab and then go back to the tab that I opened first, when the following code is executed, it tries to get the selected items from the tab I opened last -

```
TableItem[] tblItem = tableTC.getSelection();
```

Its almost as if I need something like -

```
TableItem[] tblItem = getActivePart().tableTC.getSelection();
```

When I execute getPartName(), the correct tab name is returned, however it tries to get the table data from a different part.

Code for listener -

```
Button btnEdit = new Button(cmpBtnSide, SWT.PUSH | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
btnEdit.setText("Edit");
btnEdit.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TableItem[] tblItem = tableTC.getSelection();



        }

    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well what is `tableTC`? How are you setting it when the tab changes?

Comment: tableTC is just a table which is declared at the top of my code as `static Table tableTC = null;` The table is populated initially from a look-up of a database. I would like to provide the functionality of being able to edit the data by clicking on the table and pressing an "Edit" Button which has a listener

Comment: Updated to include the code for the Button

Comment: If you declare something to be `static` there is only one instance of it - so I would guess you end up with it pointing to which ever tab set it last. You probably need a none static variable for each tab.

Comment: Hi Greg, your suggested solution worked, can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was being caused by my Table being declared as a static variable at the top of my code.

Thanks Greg for the solution!